# Using Raspberry Pi to capture police scanner audio

Tags: audio-playback

I want to take a Police Scanner, connect the headphone jack to a RaspberryPi, and capture the broadcasts that are received, so when the recording is played back it is just the transmissions, but maybe just about 5 seconds of gaps between the broadcast, saving this "recording" to a file that could be listened to at a latter time.

Has anyone set something up like this? I've found articles to connect the scanner's audio with the raspberrypi, but have not seen where it only "records" the transmissions.

Comment: Do you currently have a functioning scanner?

Comment: Would it be sufficient to record everything and strip out silences longer than 5s? Or do you have another (better?) way of telling when you get a transmission?

Comment: This link may be helpful: https://learn.adafruit.com/freq-show-raspberry-pi-rtl-sdr-scanner/overview To record audio, see the second answer of https://askubuntu.com/questions/229352/how-to-record-output-to-speakers

Comment: this question is not related to the RPi

Comment: Yes I do have a functioning Scanner, Radio Shack Pro-107

Comment: I believe removing the silences longer than 5s would be sufficient.

Comment: I do believe this  is related to the RPi. I am wanting to connect the scanner to the RPi so that I can capture the audio, but I do not want a lot of silence in the recording so the program would have to be monitoring the sound and when "someone talked on the scanner" it would capture that with a little "silence buffer", write it to a file. Then when I wanted to I could play the file and hear the traffic.

Comment: It is related to the RPi, as I want to setup an RPi to capture the sound and make it available.